# jstl/jsp print name of file beutiful

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have my tag `${file.name}` in a jsp file to display a name of file to download

`name` containt a full file name,include file extension. for example

> testfile.png
>
> a-file.zip
>
> testfile-test505454654.png
>
> a-filenum5468.docx
>
> other_file_with_a_name_very_very_very_larrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrge.pdf

Files with very long names, crash my layout.

I think the way to format the file name to shorten it but include the extention. Maybe

> testfile.png
>
> a-file.zip
>
> testfile-test505454....png     *
>
> a-filenum5468.docx
>
> other_file_with_a_na....pdf     *

How I can do?

in href no problem because it is done by id `${file.id}`

Comment: What type is `file` and what type is `name`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis file is my POJO {int id, string name} name is `String`  with Getters and Setters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `file` is a POJO, you may add a getter-method to the POJO (something like `String getShortName(){}`) that returns a short version of the file name. And then use the method in your EL expression: `${file.shortName}`.

Comment: it may be that the other answers are as convenient to separate the business logic, but this seems as fast for the time. I had not even considered, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I would write and register a custom tag that would take care of shortening the output to a maximum length

```
<custom:short value="${file.name}" var="shortFileName" />
```

The tag would take care of shortening based on defaults or values you specify in the element and putting it the result in a request attribute you can use anywhere after that declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Since the requirements can be used many times so You should go with CUSTOM Tag solution like @Sotirios Delimanolis suggested.

JSTL function ( Like c:fn ) is another solution. Using jstl function get better performance than Custom tag ( simple / classic model )

Link: http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/